# Why does torch.scatter requires a smaller shape for indices than values?

Tags: pytorch

A similar question was already asked [here](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/1d-scatter-add-requires-len-indices-len-values/23632), but I think the solution is not suited for my case.

I just wonder why it is not possible to do a `torch.scatter` operation, where my index tensor is bigger than my value tensor. In my case I have duplicate indices, e.g. the following value tensor `a` and the index tensor `idx`:

```py
a = torch.tensor([[0, 1, 0, 0],
                  [0, 0, 1, 0]])

idx = torch.tensor([[1, 1, 2, 3, 3],
                    [0, 0, 1, 2, 2]])
```

`a.scatter(-1, idx, 1)` returns:

> RuntimeError: Expected index [2, 5] to be smaller than self [2, 4] apart from dimension 1 and to be smaller size than src [2, 4]

Is there another way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

Not a solution, but a workaround:

```py
a = torch.tensor([[0, 1, 0, 0],
                  [0, 0, 1, 0]])

idx = torch.tensor([[1, 1, 2, 3, 3],
                    [0, 0, 1, 2, 2]])

rows = torch.arange(0, a.size(0))[:,None]
n_col = idx.size(1)
a[rows.repeat(1, n_col), idx] = 1
```

`rows.repeat(1, n_col)` gives the row index to the corresponding column index in `idx`.